# Difference between -moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-gradient

Tags: css, browser

What is the basic difference between -moz-linear-gradient and -webkit-gradient. I know the changes are in parameters and -moz is meant for mozilla. But why we have different CSS property for Mozilla. What does webkit represents here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most often, though, the extensions are used to release and test
>   browser features that have been developed in the preparation of W3C
>   drafts that have not yet reached Candidate Recommendation status—the
>   extensions allow these new properties to be widely tested before they
>   become available as standard CSS properties.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific

> Some of these properties have been included in draft CSS specification
>   for inclusion in the final recommendation, but are still experimental.
>   The final standard property may be different from the current prefix
>   implementation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Answer (score 0):

**Webkit CSS properties**

http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit

[WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) is an open source web browser engine. WebKit is also the name of the Mac OS X system framework version of the engine that's used by Safari, Dashboard, Mail, and many other OS X applications. WebKit's HTML and JavaScript code began as a branch of the KHTML and KJS libraries from KDE.

[CSS3 Gradients](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/)

**Introduction**

WebKit paved the way for gradients in CSS by adding support for -webkit-gradient back in early 2008, and they’ve become widely used since their introduction.

Over the past several months, the CSS Working Group has had extended discussions about making the gradient syntax easier to use, and recently Tab Atkins included a proposal in the latest draft of the Image Values and Replaced Content module. WebKit and Mozilla have now implemented this proposal so that web authors can experiment with it, and provide feedback to the Working Group. Note that the proposal is still an editor’s draft, which means that it’s still possible, and even likely to change due to user feedback.

The main goal of the new syntax is simplicity; it’s now really easy to code up common gradients, as you’ll see in the examples below. A secondary goal was to specify something where implementations were compatible across browsers.

If you’re not already running one, go and grab a recent nightly build so that you can see the examples in this post.

Here are some simple examples (note that all these examples are resizable, so you can see how resizing the box affects the gradients):

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your quotes. Don't just blindly copy and paste - that is not appropriate.